# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in send AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get the checked inputs in a variable called `reasons` and I want send  `withdrawalId` and `reasons` in an AJAX request. This is my code:

```
$('body').on('click','#submitreason', function () {
    var wdid = $('.modal').attr('id');
    var reasons = $('input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            withdrawalid: wdid,
            reasons : reasons
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'success') {
            } else  {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I try to send the AJAX request I get an error; I think this problem is because of the `reasons` variable;

```
var reasons = $('input:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
});
```

When I add `dataproccess = false;` data is sent like `[object object]` and the response is empty whenever I use `var_dump($_POST)`.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get()` to retrieve an array of integer values from `map()`:

```
var reasons = $('input:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4jknerv/) for an example of the difference between the two.

Comment: can you please checkout my question similar to this?